# Data bound radio buttons not getting styled

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm trying to use KnockoutJS with jQuery mobile and I've run into a problem where the radio buttons in a data-bound set don't get styled.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ajSq/1/)

I have a simple model that looks like this:

```
var vm = {
    options: ["option1","option2","option3"]            
}

$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

And I try and bind it like this:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-bind="foreach: options">
        <input type="radio" name="selectModel" data-bind="attr: { id: $data}, value: $data" />
        <label data-bind="attr: {for: $data}, text: $data"></label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

I can see by examining the DOM that KnockoutJS has correctly transformed my collection to (roughly) this (removing the data-bind for clarity):

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <input id="option1" type="radio" name="selectStaticModel" value="option1">
    <label for="option1">option1</label>

    <input id="option2" type="radio" name="selectStaticModel" value="option2">
    <label for="option2">option2</label>

    <input id="option3" type="radio" name="selectStaticModel" value="option3">
    <label for="option3">option3</label>
</fieldset>
```

Which if I put in statically in my HTML, it is correctly styled by jQuery Mobile.

Any idea what might be going on here? Elsewhere in the same project I have a collect that is shown in a listview and that styles just fine.

I've only tested this in FF so far.

**Update**

Search around for this, I found some [old information](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/refresh-a-form-element) that suggested applying `.checkboxradio()` to the elements to manually style them. I did that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ajSq/3/)

```
$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    $(".boundRadio").checkboxradio();
});
```

This helps some, but they are not grouped like they would be for the statically defined buttons. Each one has individually rounded corners instead of only rounding the top corners of the first item and the bottom corners of the last item.

Comment: `attr: {for: $data}, text: $data` isn't getting converted into the data you want it to, inspect element and it shows as `<label data-bind="attr: {for: $data}, text: $data" for="option1">option1</label>`

Comment: @Andy: I think it is. I expect the text to be `option1`, which it is, and I expect `for` to be set to `option1` as well, which again, it is.

Comment: According to your update, if to watch generated HTML you would see that some css classes are not in proper places. I think you need set this css classes by your self, not as it works for static radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Think I've fixed it. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ajSq/4/)

I added this after applying the binding:

```
$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    $(".boundRadio").checkboxradio();
    $("#boundFS").controlgroup();
});
```

Where `boundFS` is the id I assigned to the parent fieldset and `.boundRadio` is a class applied to all the radio buttons in my template.

Unless somebody has a better, cleaner way to handle this, I'll close this question.