# Initial transition when applying styles

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm using jQuery Mobile with some dynamic content added with KnockoutJS after making an AJAX call. This is causing all kinds of problems since jQuery mobile applies it's styles and transforms the HTML before the binding has a chance to kick in. I tried a few different methods for handling this, but it seems that it's not well documented in the jQuery mobile docs.

Right now, I'm trying this after the completion of the AJAX call:

```
ko.applyBindings(ws);
$.getScript("Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js", function () {
    $("#index").fadeIn();
});
```

I set `display:none` for all the pages so that they aren't visible before the template has been applied (by `applyBindings`) and jQuery mobile has been applied. This works, except when it completes, the content pops-in rather jarringly. Is there a way to smooth out that transition? Clearly jQuery mobile automatically makes the first page visible, because my `fadeIn` has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try refreshing the jquery mobile widget after applying your changes.

```
$("#myddl").selectmenu("refresh");
```

or

```
$("#mylistview).listview("refresh");
```

Similar methods exist for most of the jquery mobile enhanced controls.

Comment: PS: It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Is it the transition or is the transition an attempt to solve your issue. Not sure my answer addresses your needs.

Comment: I've tried that approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648739/data-bound-radio-buttons-not-getting-styled) which works, but I have lots of controls and it's a pain to have to find every control and call the associated method, especially since it doesn't appear to be documented in the [JQuery Mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/). I thought this might be a better solution, since my data won't change after it's loaded (no items added or removed from lists, for example). It works, but that pop-in is annoying.

Comment: Would this be a more global approach?`$('#mypage').page("destroy").page();`

Comment: As it turns out, that does really weird things with sliders. I had one slider and it turn it into two! Ultimately, sliders have been causing me so much trouble that I've gone back to basically what you had because I can't get sliders to work (and properly bound) unless I explicitly walk through the elements I want and call `.slider()` on them.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't fix my initial problem of trying to hide the UI before it's finished binding (because now jq mobile is being applied before the binding is finished).